# If fixed timesteps are unreliable across web platforms, what can I use in my game loop?

Tags: javascript

As I have found out in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312906/why-does-setinterval-run-at-different-speeds), `window.setInterval` is not the best choice for a cross-platform game loop. What is my alternative for a game loop in Javascript that will (attempt to) run at the same speed on all devices?

Comment: Also, you'll want to look into using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) over something like `setInterval()`

Comment: You shouldn't assume your timesteps are fixed for a local game either. Always measure your time step and make sure only the appearance of the game is affected by a non standard interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use equal intervals for game loop. Instead of this use `time_delta` (current_time - last_update_time). Send `time_delta` to  game object's update method and update position and other parameters depending on time_delta. For example, simple object moving with const velocity will be:

```
function update(time_delta) {
    position = position + velocity * time_delta;
}
```

In this case, you don't need to set fixed frame per second and allow game to update state as fast as possible.

Comment: Good but rather incomplete answer. I'll just leave this here: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

In sum, use fixed step delta times, it gives better accuracy for physics integration and is more predictable.

Comment: you could simplify this to `position += velocity * time_delta`